# SQL: GROUP BY where a column is unique

Tags: database, sql-server

So I have this one giant table e.g.

<kbd>PROD_ID</kbd><kbd>GEOG_ID</kbd><kbd>TIME_ID</kbd><kbd>VALUE1</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>JAN</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>FEB</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>JAN</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>FEB</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>TT</kbd>     <kbd>MARCH</kbd>  <kbd>100</kbd>

And I want to receive Jan and Feb data only in the geography MT. Then sum the Value1's together where PROD_ID matches.

So the end result is:

<kbd>PROD_ID</kbd><kbd>GEOG_ID</kbd><kbd>VALUE1</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>200</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>200</kbd>

I have managed to get the data down to TIME_ID only using:

SELECT PROD_ID, GEOG_ID, TIME_ID, VALUE1 FROM database WHERE GEOG_ID = 'MT' AND TIME_ID IN ('JAN', 'FEB')

so I have :

<kbd>PROD_ID</kbd><kbd>GEOG_ID</kbd><kbd>TIME_ID</kbd><kbd>VALUE1</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>JAN</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>FEB</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>JAN</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>MT</kbd>     <kbd>FEB</kbd>    <kbd>100</kbd>

but now I am unsure how to use the group by function on PROD_ID since TIME_ID is unique.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks!

Comment: I've gotta say "egads that is ugly markdown in there" but it *works*. Do you have a tool to generate tables like this?

Comment: I just googled a markdown and came across: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables then just used that since it worked haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TIME_ID in the where clause without selecting it, meaning it doesn't have to go in the group by statement.

```
SELECT PROD_ID, GEOG_ID, SUM(VALUE1) AS TOTAL
FROM database 
WHERE GEOG_ID = 'MT' 
AND TIME_ID IN ('JAN', 'FEB')
GROUP BY PROD_ID, GEOG_ID
```

Comment: @Matt You are missing a comma between PROD_ID and GEOG_ID in the group by clause.

Comment: Accidentally deleted comment so for reference: I had SELECT PROD_ID, GEOG_ID, SUM(VALUE1) AS TOTAL
FROM database 
WHERE GEOG_ID = 'MT' 
AND TIME_ID IN ('JAN', 'FEB')
GROUP BY PROD_ID GEOG_ID

Comment: If you have GEOG_ID = 'MT' in your where clause then you don't need to group by it and keep GEOG_ID out of your select clause.